# Outdated Udacity course that is 3 years old now will not identify color

Tags: swift, colors, xcode9

[Im not sure why it will nit let me bring in the blue color have looked for multiple resources before posting here and why it is saying the UIView "has no member"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjljO.png)

trying to learn Xcode on swift 4 with 3 year old videos is proving to be more difficult than I thought.

Comment: Find a tutorial that uses at least Swift 3. Tutorials that use Swift 2 code will be a huge burden when trying to learn Swift 3 or 4. Swift 2 to Swift 3 was a huge change. Almost everything changes. Swift 3 to Swift 4 has very few changes.

Comment: What kind of class is `self.view.addSubView()` called from?  Is it a UIView??

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues. First being the correct reference for the color. That I can help with. `UIColor` has a method that returns the blue color and should be used in place of `blue()`:

```
UIColor.blue()
```

As far as your second error goes, I don't know what kind of class you're calling `addSubView()` from but it may just be a symptom of the first error. If my proposed change doesn't work, provide some additional information and I'll be glad to help you.

Comment: I appreciate it I ended up watching a few swift 4 videos while I was waiting and found the solution to be button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: .normal)
        self.view.addSubview(button)